# how to implement radio button in contact form 7 with different value and label

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

i want to implement this section in contact form 7.please help me

```
 <div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="1">Option 1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="2">Option 2</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio disabled">
      <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="3">Option 3</label>
    </div>
```

Comment: why not simply use your code as is? You'll need to hook the cf7 [wpcf7_validate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29504337/how-do-i-check-if-email-submitted-via-contact-form-7-exists-in-my-database) filter and look for your radio field in the $_POST array.   To show the radio value selection in the email notification, you'll need to customise your mail body with the [wpcf7_mail_components](https://orbisius.com/blog/hook-contact-form-7-wordpress-plugin-sending-email-p2200) filter before the mail is sent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this easely, putting pipe (|) on the input like this:

```
[select name_input "Visible Value|actual-form-value"]
```

where `Visible Value = (Front-end Value)` and `actual-form-value = (Input Custom Value)`.

Your code will be like this:

```
[radio optradio "Option 1|1" "Option 2|2" "Option 3|3"]
```

Take a look at [the documentation:](http://contactform7.com/selectable-recipient-with-pipes/)

Comment: @SubhankarDutta I hope this helped you  =)

Comment: @Mario62RUS if you are waiting to see this change in DOM, you will not see. But it will work. Can you share your code with me? Maybe I can help you!

Comment: The author of the plugin writes that there is no such possibility and offers to use HTML
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/radio-button-different-value-and-label/
Fanky solution is better.

Comment: @Mario62RUS if you test this code you'll see that it works, as you can see in comments. The solution came from the official documentation: https://contactform7.com/selectable-recipient-with-pipes/.
Use down votes carefully because reputation it's too hard to get and my answer can help some of people. If it not your case you don't need to use down vote. As I told you, if you want, share your cade and I see what can I do for you.

Comment: It work for select, not for radio.

Comment: [select menu-586 "a|b" "c|d" "e|f"] not work

Answer (score 3):

Sadly it seems the only way to have the value (different from the label) present in DOM is to hide the original CF7's label.

Add the radios separately while keeping the name. Your labeling text next to them, you can wrap them in `<label>` tags. No newlines here, because CF7 would interpret them as `<br>`s.

```
<div id="myradios"><label>[radio optradio use_label_element default:1 "1"] Option 1</label><label>[radio amount use_label_element "2"] Option 2</label><label>[radio amount use_label_element "3"] Option 3</label></div>
```

Now hide the CF7's labels with CSS:

```
#myradios .wpcf7-list-item-label{
    display:none;
}
```

Unfortunately you can't use it without default:1 on some of the elements - if you do and the user doesn't check any, the error message will appear under each of the radios (CF7 docs say radios are required by default).